# Continuous memory leak in event callback from Accord VideoCaptureDevice

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, bitmap

I'm getting a steady severe leak within my event callback from my Accord VideoCaptureDevice for each frame image Bitmap from my USB camera.

Initialization:

```
public static Bitmap latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap = null;                 
// latest camera frame FOV (complete Field Of View) bitmap
```

Event:

```
private static void EVENT_camera_frame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs camera_frame_event)
{
    if( latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap != null )
    {
        latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Dispose();
    }

    latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap = rotation_filter.Apply(new Bitmap(camera_frame_Bitmap.Width, camera_frame_Bitmap.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb));
 }
```

If I comment out "latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap = rotation_filter..." then no leak.

Comment: I think it is because you used new Bitmap(....) Try using it. This new bitmap is not disposed?

Comment: What is `Apply`? Does it return the passed-in Bitmap or a new one?

Comment: I assume you are using AForge?

Comment: To TheGeneral:  Accord

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by following these great suggestions by the 'masters'...

The NewFrame event is raised on a worker thread. But the Paint event is raised on the UI thread. You cannot use Clone(), you must make a deep copy. Use the new Bitmap(Image) constructor. You also cannot safely assign the PictureBox.Image property in the worker thread, you must use its BeginInvoke() method to ensure the assignment occurs on the UI thread. – Hans Passant Apr 16 at 21:48

Besides what Hans said, try making a copy of the Bitmap returned by the NewFrame Handler, changing Bitmap camera_frame_Bitmap = camera_frame_event.Frame; to Bitmap camera_frame_Bitmap = new Bitmap(camera_frame_event.Frame);. Also, see if you can safely Clone() it. – Jimi

Comment: You do realise your answer has absolutely nothing in common with your question? And talks about every topic that you have garnered from a history of seemingly unrelated questions. Just saying